# How to open or download pdf files

Tags: dart, flutter

I have an app what do querys from my sql database and i need to download or open files from the database. The files route are saved in the database so i need a way to download it or open in the app.The files type are pdf and jpg.

Comment: As written, it's not clear as to what you're asking. Please edit your question to include details as to what environment, what database, what kind of app, what kind of queries, etc. Providing a [mcve] and/or a detailed explanation of what exactly you want to achieve will allow us to better help you.

Comment: Try this 
https://github.com/anthonydonx/FlutterPdfDownloader